# I have a MessageBox in my Visual C++ Win32 that cannot be closed! What is going on?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a message box that simply cannot be closed, and I am not sure why. It is created within my window procedure for a dialog box which was created like so:

```
hwnd = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, WndProc);
```

Below is the WndProc code with the problem. It is the MessageBox call that has the problem, the OK button does nothing, nor does hitting the "X" on that message box.

```
BOOL CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HBRUSH bgBrush;
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        bgBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(65, 65, 66));
        return TRUE;

    case WM_CTLCOLORDLG:
        return (INT_PTR)(bgBrush);

    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(200, 200, 200));
        return (INT_PTR)(bgBrush);

    case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        USBEnumerateDev();
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
                       switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                       {
                       case IDC_SELECTPROFILE:
                           switch (HIWORD(wParam))
                           {
                           case BN_CLICKED:
                               int res = CommonFileDialog.BasicFileOpen(hwnd);
                               if (res == TRUE)
                               {
                                   int len = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDITWLAN));
                                   if (len > 0)
                                   {
                                       int i;
                                       wchar_t* buf;

                                       buf = (wchar_t*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, len + 1);
                                       GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDITWLAN, buf, len + 1);



                                       GlobalFree((HANDLE)buf);
                                   }
                               }
                               break;
                           }
                           break;

                       case IDC_PROGRAM:
                           switch (HIWORD(wParam))
                           {
                           case BN_CLICKED:
                               int len = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDITWLAN));
                               if (len > 0)
                               {
                                   int i, fileSize;
                                   LPSTR XMLfilename, buf;
                                   FILE *fXMLfile;

                                   XMLfilename = (LPSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, len + 1);
                                   GetDlgItemTextA(hwnd, IDC_EDITWLAN, XMLfilename, len + 1);
                                   fopen_s(&fXMLfile, XMLfilename, "r");
                                   fseek(fXMLfile, 0L, SEEK_END);
                                   fileSize = ftell(fXMLfile);
                                   fseek(fXMLfile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
                                   buf = (LPSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, fileSize);
                                   fread(buf, 1, fileSize, fXMLfile);
                                   DBG("fileSize: %d", fileSize);
                                   if (USBSetProfile(buf, fileSize))
                                       MessageBox(hwnd, L"Programmed!", L"PC -> USB", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                                   GlobalFree((HANDLE)XMLfilename);
                                   GlobalFree((HANDLE)buf);
                                   //
                               }
                           }
                           break;
                       }
    }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What gives? I have tried both calling MessageBox with the window handle and with NULL, same thing.

Comment: Chances are that the rest of your WndProc code is doing (or not doing) something that is causing the close message to be discarded/ignored before the MessageBox() can process it. What does the rest of your WndProc actually look like?

Comment: @RemyLebeau http://pastebin.com/gDdQVR92 Its somewhat large so I PasteBin'd it. Also note there is a second thread which is reading from USB, but is not associated with a dialog box. However disabling that thread doesn't solve the problem. Could it be that my message loop is in my main thread?

Comment: Make sure the MessageBox call is initiated from the same thread that contains the message loop.

Comment: Your `WndProc()` is calling `DefWindowProc()`, but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx) specifically says NOT to do that: "*Although the dialog box procedure is similar to a window procedure, **it must not call the DefWindowProc function to process unwanted messages**. Unwanted messages are processed internally by the dialog box window procedure.*".

Comment: @MarkRansom: `MessageBox()` runs its own message loop internally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Getting rid of DefWindowProc fixed it. Please post it as an answer so I can upvote you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `WndProc()` is calling `DefWindowProc()`, but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx) specifically says NOT to do that:

> Although the dialog box procedure is similar to a window procedure, **it must not call the DefWindowProc function to process unwanted messages.** Unwanted messages are processed internally by the dialog box window procedure.

Answer (score 2):

this is a mix of window procedure and dialog procedure. those are different and have different rules.

also be careful with the return value. you are supposed to return TRUE for the cases you handled, and FALSE for those you did not. you return 0 (FALSE) always.